# Converting an Object of Arrays into Objects of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, array.prototype.map

Currently my data looks like this

```
{
    numberOne: [{
        timestamp: 3829383,
        value: 20323.23
    }],
    numberTwo: [{
        timestamp: 2382342,
        value: 120912.1
    }]
    ...
}
```

And I want to get it into this format

```
{
    numberOne: {
        timestamp: 3829383,
        value: 20323.23
    },
    numberTwo: {
        timestamp: 2382342,
        value: 120912.1
    }
    ...
}
```

I've tried `Object.assign`, `.map()`, `.filter()`... nothing seems to work!

Any thoughts on how I could make this work would be very helpful

Comment: Your data _can't_ look like that first example.

Comment: Your input data doesn't looks valid JS code.

Comment: Your data cannot look like this `[
        timestamp: 3829383,
        value: 20323.23
    ]`. its wrong syntax

Comment: Are you sure it looks like that? The former is not valid json nor a valid js object.

Comment: Apologies, yes you're all correct - I have amended the code.

Comment: Is there always only one item in each array?

Comment: Loop through the keys and update each value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate the entries in the object, pull out the first item in each array and create an object with the key and the item.

```js
const data = { numberOne: [{ timestamp: 3829383, value: 20323.23 }], numberTwo: [{ timestamp: 2382342, value: 120912.1 }] }

const transform = (arr) => 
    Object.entries(arr).reduce((acc,[k,[v]]) => (acc[k] = v, acc), {})

console.log(transform(data))
```

Or, you can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const data = { numberOne: [{ timestamp: 3829383, value: 20323.23 }], numberTwo: [{ timestamp: 2382342, value: 120912.1 }] }

const transform = (arr) => 
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr).map(([k,[v]]) => [k, v]))

console.log(transform(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the input object by using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and some [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) into the desired output:

```js
const data = {
  numberOne: [{ timestamp: 3829383, value: 20323.23 }],
  numberTwo: [{ timestamp: 2382342, value: 120912.1 }]
};

const result = Object.entries(data)
                     .reduce((r, [k, [v]]) => (r[k] = v, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for (var key in obj)` loop and set the desired value for each key:

```js
var obj = {
    numberOne: [{ timestamp: 3829383, value: 20323.23 }],
    numberTwo: [{ timestamp: 2382342, value: 120912.1 }]
};
console.log("Before -->", obj);

for (var key in obj) {
   obj[key] = obj[key][0]; // take item 0 from each array
}
console.log("After -->", obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the object using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate over the [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (which gives you an array of a key and value):

```js
const data = {
  numberOne: [{
    timestamp: 3829383,
    value: 20323.23
  }],
  numberTwo: [{
    timestamp: 2382342,
    value: 120912.1
  }]
}

// Grab the entries and iterate over each
// destructuring out the key and value from the array
const out = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {

  // Set the key on the initial object (acc), and set
  // the value to be the first element of the value array
  acc[key] = value[0];

  // Return the initial object (acc) for the next iteration
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```